# How to retrieve profile2 form fields using rest services?

Tags: users, services

We've created a registration form using the [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module. I want to render this form on an Android app and because of that I want to retrieve the form fields using the rest services.

My question: is there a way to retrieve form fields with their type so that I can write a module on android side to display the form based on the fields type?

For example: If the field type is textfield on the drupal side, I'll be creating a TextView on the android side.

I want to retrieve data in **JSON format** because

1. I want to parse the **form-data**
2. I want to create a list of field. Each field should have a type.
3. Once I have the list of fields, I'll be creating similar fields on the mobile side according the android form interface.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module only returns a **JSON/XML** representation of the data. It doesn't render an HTML form or associated fields (nor Android views/elements). It also doesn't provide metadata about the fields, just data values.

**Services** can be extended though (see the included `.api.php` files), so it would be possible, if a bit long-winded, for you to implement this yourself. You could expose a resource which queries the `field_info` and `field_info_instance` tables for metadata about the fields, for example.

Comment: Thanks Clive, I've updated my question. Please have a look.